# Select rows from a table where a column containing delimiter seperated strings matching atleast one string from another set of strings in hive

Tags: hive, delimiter, string-matching

[image]

In the table "App" column contains a long string **(ex -"aa;bb;cc")** . I have another set of strings which have several strings **('aa','bb','cc')** . I want to select rows which **atleast contains one**  of the strings from **('aa','bb','cc')**.

Comment: second string contains single quotes and first one does not, right?

Comment: yes 1st one is a long string .inside words are delimitered with ; . second one has individual strings .

Comment: is the number of elements is limited in second string?

Answer (score 0):

If your test string has limited number of elements, you can split it and check each element exists in App using array_contains().

Demo:

```
 with your_data as 
 ( --Test dataset, replace it with your table
  select stack(5, --5 tuples
                  'aa\\;bb\\;cc',
                  'dd\\;cc\\;ff',
                  'ww\\;xx\\;yy',
                  'ww\\;aa\\;yy',
                  'pp\\;bb\\;qq'                                
               ) as App
 ),

 test_string as 
 ( --This can be also a dataset, or replace it with string parameter
   --according to your requirements
 select "'aa','bb','cc'" as str2 --contains values in single quotes delimited by comma
 )

 select App from
 (
 select App, split(App, '\\;') AppArray, 
        split(regexp_replace(t.str2,"'",''),',') as TestArray2 --remove single quotes and split
   from your_data 
        cross join test_string t 
        --cross join here. This is one string example only. Rewrite join according to your dataset.
 )s
 where array_contains(AppArray, TestArray2[0]) or --First element exists
       array_contains(AppArray, TestArray2[1]) or --second
       array_contains(AppArray, TestArray2[2])    --third
 ;
```

Result:

```
OK
aa;bb;cc
dd;cc;ff
ww;aa;yy
pp;bb;qq
Time taken: 41.853 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```